# Can my project(react 15) use a dependency that using react 16?

Tags: reactjs

Can a project using react 15 depend on a package which is using react 16?

For example: 
Project A uses React 16
Project B uses React 15 and Project A, can that work?

Comment: I recommend to read the documentation - https://reactjs.org/blog/2017/09/26/react-v16.0.html `if your app runs in 15.6 without any warnings, it should work in 16`

Comment: I have tried doing that in a React 15 project and found that the two different React insances appear to be in conflict and the app won't load properly. My guess is that the two React instances would be running two different virtual DOM tree so they won't be in sync. You should probably try loading an older version of your dependency or upgrade your project to Fiber.

Comment: @Kunukn that doesn't answer my question.

Comment: the answer is "it depends", on which features of 16 are being used ( like error boundaries)

Comment: It all depends how your dependencies are installed. There should be only one react version in your dependencies otherwise you will have a problem - the app won't run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer: no. Project A pulls in React 16 as requirement and Project B pulls in React 15 as requirement. You can't load two different react instances, the solution is simple; bump the React dependency of Project B, or make React a peerDependency and support 15 and 16.